# Replace spaces between 2 character - @keyframes and left curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create script by JavaScript reformat my CSS code so I should first to remove all spaces and taps then add 4 spaces before all properties

So I have only One Problem with @keyframes and @media screen - the script replaces the spaces between all words and I don't want to replace the spaces between @ and { characters to keep keyframes and media screen works fine

**I tried RegExp Like This** `\s[^@.*\n{]`

but it but not working please any one help me to don't replace the text between @ - { characters ..

**Example**

```
Elem.innerHTML = textarea.value.replace(/\s[^@.*\n{]/g , "");
```

Now it's like this
`@keyframesfade{from{transform:rotate(0);}to{transform:rotate(360deg);}}`

> **I want it to be like this**
>
> `@keyframes fade{from{transform:rotate(0);}to{transform:rotate(360deg);}}`

Comment: Why just not add an additional line of code where you `str.replace('@keyframes', '@keyframes ')` ?

Comment: Cause I don't want to use it for this only I want it to keep spaces between @ and { in any text

Answer (score 1):

`(?<!@(\w|\s)+)\s|\s(?=\{)` works for your examples (including those you commented on this answer). It turns

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
 elem1 {
  background: red;
 }
 .elem2 {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
}
```

into

```
@media screen and (max-width:750px){elem1{background:red;}.elem2{font-size:20px;}}
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine - but it's need dot and square brackets [] to ignore all spaces between @ and { ... without dot it's only ignore the first word it's should be like this `(?<![@\w.+])\s`

Comment: I tested that regex, and it results in `@keyframes fade {from {transform:rotate(0);}to {transform:rotate(360deg);}}`, which doesn't match what you want.

Comment: When I tried to use your regex with `@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {  elem1 { background: red; } .elem2 { font-size: 20px; } } ` it's give me this `@media screenand(max-width:750px){.elem1{background:red;}.elem2{font-size:20px;;}} ` when I added dot and square brackets to your regex `(?<![@\w.+])\s` it's ignores all spaces between @ _ {.. can you help me to ignore all spaces between @ _{ only and remove all another spaces ... #Note The Example above have spaces and new lines but I can't create new lines in this comments........

Comment: @RootZxcvpn Well, `(?<!@(\w|\s)+)\s|\s(?=\{)` will achieve your goal for your second example. It will convert it to `@media screen and (max-width:750px){elem1{background:red;}.elem2{font-size:20px;}}`. I'll update my answer. And yes, it's somewhat annoying that comments don't allow new lines.

Comment: Thank you so much it's works fine ... I'm still trying to learn RegExp - I looked on references in w3schools but I can't understanding it well there's no many examples can you tell me name for another website explain it better –

Comment: @RootZxcvpn Regex has less to it than I first expected. I only learnt it 3 months ago. The w3schools page (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) was most helpful for me, but https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/a-practical-beginners-guide-to-regex-regular-expressions-2faccbda117d was also somewhat helpful. Many webpages had very poor explanations however; a few had mistakes, and many include regex characters not supported in JavaScript, which you have to watch for.

Comment: @RootZxcvpn By the way, you could've used https://cssminifier.com/. It has the same effect.

Comment: I know that there's many sites to do that but I was just want to create it by myself to improve my experience thank you very much